# Unable to watch TextEditingController in riverpod

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I'm trying to watch to TextEditingController

keyword provider is not updated.

```
final textEditingController =
Provider.autoDispose<TextEditingController>((ref) => TextEditingController());

final keyword = Provider.autoDispose<String>((ref) {
  return ref.watch(interviewsLookupEditingController.select((value) => value.text));
});
```

Is it because TextEditingController mutable? or why?

Comment: Can you include how you are using this. Also you can use String instead of controller

Comment: I need to use controller functions like: clear()

Comment: You can also set empty string or null if you make it nullable stringProvider